# Add frames to a gif without changing its url

Tags: url, addition, gif

TLDR I need a simple process to add individual PNG images to gifs easly without changing the url of the gif

I think that I'll have to change gif hosting Web pages to do it. I'm looking for a technical solution which allows me to do this quickly because I'll be doing it lots over a corse of...well years

Comment: Do you have access to the webserver? Through which protocol? `ssh`?

Comment: 不No but I'm willing 至to get 它it